# Notify-send won't show notification unless run with sudo

Tags: 13.10, permissions, sudo, notification, notify-osd

I have just tried to use `notify-send` on my 13.10 machine and can't get it to work without using `sudo` with it.

I don't know what details can I provide with this issue.

My `notify-osd` version :

```
$ ii  notify-osd      0.9.35+13.10.20130917.1-0ubuntu1-leolik~ppa0  amd64        daemon that displays passive pop-up notifications
```

On regular version for 13.10 there was the same issue.

**EDIT**

```
$ ll /usr/bin/notify-send
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14720 wrz 10 16:12 /usr/bin/notify-send
```

Comment: can you see if it has a file in /etc/pam.d

Comment: @nux It doesn't. What should I do now ?

Comment: go to `/usr/bin` and check for the permission on executable of notify-send

Comment: @Nullpointer `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: What is the permission of `/user/bin` folder?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam You meant `/usr/bin` ? `drwxr-xr-x  root root `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to reinstall it with:
`sudo apt-get purge notify-osd && sudo apt-get install notify-osd`

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help.

Comment: So maybe as @Null pointer said - try `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/notify-send`

Comment: I have the permissions set the way you described: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15K wrz 10  2013 /usr/bin/notify-send`